# Remove the URL labels in IEEE bibliography

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran, ieee-style

The following figure is generated by

```
\documentclass[10pt, conference]{IEEEtran}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,myReferences}
```

The `myReferences` is simpe as follows:

```
@Misc{Pig,
  title =    {{Apache Pig}},
  url = {http://pig.apache.org}
}

@Misc{MAT,
  title =    {{Eclipse Memory Analyzer}},
  url = {http://www.eclipse.org/mat}
}
```

[image]

The labels (i.e., [Online] and Available) are automatically generated by IEEEtran.bst. Is there a way to remove the label "Available"? Thanks!

The IEEE templates can be found [here](http://www.ieee.org/conferences_events/conferences/publishing/templates.html).

Comment: If you have been asked to use a specific template, then you use that template and do **not** modify it. You are the content provider, not the designer. Journal editors get rather annoyed when they receive contributions where the author have changed things just because he/she did not like the journals design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the information on the URL in the `note` field instead of the `url` field:

```
@Misc{Pig,
  title =    {{Apache Pig}},
  note = {\url{http://pig.apache.org}}
}

@Misc{MAT,
  title =    {{Eclipse Memory Analyzer}},
  note = {\url{http://www.eclipse.org/mat}}
}
```

(the command `\url` change the font and, together with `\usepackage{hyperref}`, adds a link to the corresponding URL)

Answer (score 1):

Download the IEEEtran.bst from the https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex?lang=en

Then open the IEEEtran.bst and modify the following line
FUNCTION {default.is.use.url} { #1 }

to

FUNCTION {default.is.use.url} { #0 }